# Set a variable from a Source Result in Azure Data Factory

Tags: variables, set, azure-data-factory

I've been trying to do this. From a data source pointing to my first database, I would like to have a date-time reference that I then use into another source on a different database as a parameter to limit the number of registers.

I will be something like this:

Source_1:  Implement the next code and save the result in a variable @dateRef.

```
SELECT IIF(UpdateDtm > CreatedDtm, UpdateDtm, COALESCE(CreatedDtm,UpdateDtm, cast('1900-01-01' as smalldatetime))) as dateRef
FROM 
(
    SELECT MAX(UpdatedDtm) as UpdateDtm, MAX(CreatedDtm) as  CreatedDtm
    FROM schema.table
) max_value
```

Source_2: Use @dateRef on my select statement.

```
select  Client, location
from schema.table
where date >= @dateRef
```

I'm brand new with Data Factory, for the last years I've been working with Pentaho where I could do this kind of operations, but here is a little confusing for me. I looked for some examples. However, nothing seems to show the scenario that I want to implement.

Regards,

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: hi,any progress here?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your needs i think you could consider using Azure Function Activity to execute above sql:

```
SELECT IIF(UpdateDtm > CreatedDtm, UpdateDtm, COALESCE(CreatedDtm,UpdateDtm, cast('1900-01-01' as smalldatetime))) as dateRef FROM  (
    SELECT MAX(UpdatedDtm) as UpdateDtm, MAX(CreatedDtm) as  CreatedDtm
    FROM schema.table ) max_value
```

Then you output the result from Azure Function so that you could use it in the next step.No need to set it in the variable. You could refer the value with `@activity('Azure Function1').output`

Next step is using above output in the sql,you can't just write `@activity('Azure Function1').output` into sql.You have to use `@concat()` method. For example:

```
@concat('select  Client, location
from schema.table
where date >=', activity('Azure Function1').output)
```